# Conditions in a list comprehension , finding possibilities

Tags: haskell, permutation, list-comprehension

there are 3 keys and 3 locks, and i have to write a code to show the possible tries. Rules are:

- Second key never can be placed before the first one.
- No keys can be tried more than once.
- First key cannot be placed as the first one.
- and you can't place them in the order 3 - 2 - 1
- and as a tip, this is given:  [(x,y,z) | x <- [1..3], ]

---

I want to change this code in a way that, instead of " fst <- [3] " it says; " fst cannot be [1] "
and I also want to add that 2 cannot come before 1. I tried it with (elemIndex 2 (x,y,z)) > (elemIndex 1 (x,y,z)) 
 but it didn't work. I would appreciate for some ideas.

```
d = [(x,y,z) | x <- [1..3], y <- [1..3], z <-[1..3], fst <- [3] , tail <- 1], x /= y, y /= z, x /= z]
```

Comment: First your brackets don't appear to be matching. Second, are you purposefully naming your variables `fst` and `tail` or did you intend for these to be used as functions? What are you trying to do with this code? What are the requirements?

Comment: It's not very clear to me what the specifications are. Please first state what you want to achieve, how you want to achieve it, is the second part.

Comment: I wanted to use them as functions. - I edited the question, so i hope it is more clear now

Comment: Since the code you gave doesn't compile, may I suggest that, as a general guide, you always have a version of your code that does compile. Then make a change and, once that compiles, go from there.  So, I'd trim the expression you gave to `d = [(x,y,z) | x <- [1..3], y <- [1..3], z <-[1..3]]`.  Examine that and play with it, change it, run it, 'til you understand what's going on there.  Then, to attack your requirement "fst cannot be [1]"... write this: ` d = [(x,y,z) | x <- [1..3], y <- [1..3], z <-[1..3],x/=1]`.  Play with that, change the x to y, change the 1 to 2, add a `y/=1`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
d = [(3, y, z) | y <- [1..2], z <-[1..2], y /= z, y /= 2]
```

which gives

```
[(3,1,2)]
```

**Explanation**

> First key cannot be placed as the first one.

and

> Second key never can be placed before the first one.

imply that `x` cannot be 1 or 2, and hence must be 3. This gives

```
[(3, y, z) | y <- [1..2], z <-[1..2]
```

Since

> No keys can be tried more than once.

we also have

```
, y != z
```

Finally

> Second key never can be placed before the first one.

gives

, y /= 2]

In fact, with some thought, you could argue that you can just write

```
d = [(3, 1, 2)]
```